# Loading CSV with Pandas - Array's not parsed correctly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a dataset which I transformed to CSV as potential input for a keras auto encoder.
The loading of the CSV works flawless with `pandas.read_csv()` but the data types are not correct.

The csv solely contains two colums: **label** and **features** whereas the label column contains strings and the features column arrays with signed integers ([-1, 1]). So in general pretty simple structure.

To get two different dataframes for further processing I created them via:

`labels = pd.DataFrame(columns=['label'], data=csv_data, dtype='U')`
and

`features = pd.DataFrame(columns=['features'], data=csv_data)`

in both cases I got wrong datatypes as both are marked as `object` typed dataframes. **What am I doing wrong?**
For the features it is even harder because the parsing returns me a `pandas.sequence` that contains the array as string: `['[1, ..., 1]']`.

So I tried a tedious workaround by parsing the string back to an numpy array via `.to_numpy()` a python cast for every element and than an `np.assarray()` - but the type of the dataframe is still incorrect. I think this could not be the general approach how to solve this task. As I am fairly new to pandas I checked some tutorials and the API but in most cases a cell in a dataframe rather contains a single value instead of a complete array. Maybe my overall design of the dataframe ist just not suitable for this task.

Any help appreacheated!

Comment: Do you have null values in features? Also if possible please sare sample of the csv data

Comment: i have zeros but not null values on row of the csv looks like: a_b,[1,-1,0,1,..,0,-1] where 0, 1 and -1 are my only values in the array

Comment: So is this an acurate representation of your data?  
`featurea [1,0,1,1,1,1,]`

`featureb [1,0,1,1,1,1,]`

`featurec [1,0,1,1,1,1,]`

`featured [1,0,1,1,1,1,]`

`featuree [1,0,1,1,1,1,]`

Comment: absolutely! a very basic structure without additional properties.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the file as string but you have a python list as a column you need to evaluate it to get the list.
I am not sure of the use case but you can split the labels for a more readable dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
features = ["featurea","featureb","featurec","featured","featuree"]
labels = ["[1,0,1,1,1,1]","[1,0,1,1,1,1]","[1,0,1,1,1,1]","[1,0,1,1,1,1]","[1,0,1,1,1,1]"]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(features, labels)), 
               columns =['Features', 'Labels']) 

import ast
#convert Strings to lists
df['Labels'] = df['Labels'].map(ast.literal_eval)
df.index  = df['Features']

#Since list itself might not be useful you can split and expand it to multiple columns
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df['Labels'].values.tolist(),index= df.index)
```

**Output**

```
          0  1  2  3  4  5
Features
featurea  1  0  1  1  1  1
featureb  1  0  1  1  1  1
featurec  1  0  1  1  1  1
featured  1  0  1  1  1  1
featuree  1  0  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried your solutions and it is way more elegant than the procedure before. I noticed just a few things: 1. literal_eval does not work for the 1_3_3 scheme as it evaluates it to 133 but this is not a real issue 2. the new feature dataframe has the shape 15,1 that indicated 15 rows with one entry each - therefore the expansion you recommended does not work properly. Maybe it's the same issue as the entry get treated as a string - but I already investigate that.

Comment: Thanks for stating the expansion of the columns - i re-parsed my csv to rows with: labelA, 1, -1, 0 ..., 1, 2 - and skipped the corresponding headers - now it works as indented the only downside is that i now working on indices instead of columns but this is not a real minus

Answer (score 0):

The input csv was **formatted incorrectly**, therefore the parsing *was accurate* but *not what i intended*. **I expanded the real columns** and skipped the header to have a column for every array entry - **now panda recognize the types and the correct dimensions.**